# Why am I getting a NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, file, stringtokenizer

I'm sure this just comes down to me not understanding StringTokenizer, but I can't find an answer for this anywhere. Why am I getting this error?

```
     import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NHLDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("nhlstats");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        PlayerRecord pr;
        NHLStats list = new NHLStats();
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String line = inputFile.next();
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
            while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
                System.out.print(token.nextToken());
                System.out.print(token.nextToken());
                String name = token.nextToken();
                String position = token.nextToken();
                String team = token.nextToken();
                int gp = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                int g = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                int a = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                int pim = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                int sog = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                int gwg = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                pr = new PlayerRecord(name, position, team, gp, g, a, pim, sog, gwg);
                list.add(pr);
            }
        }
        list.enumerate();
    }
}
```

I am reading data from a specific file which has the same amount of tokens on each line

(ex. 
St.Louis    RW  TB  48  17  43  14  112 2

Stamkos     C   TB  48  29  28  32  157 2

Ovechkin    RW  WSH 48  32  24  36  220 4

Crosby      C   PIT 36  15  41  16  124 1 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

when you do String line = inputFile.next(); line is just St.Louis, so when you try nextToken you get the exception

this works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MyStringTokenizer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
        File file = new File("nhlstats");
        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        //Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        PlayerRecord pr;
        NHLStats list = new NHLStats();
        String line="";
        while((line=input.readLine())!=null)
        {
            if(!line.equals("")){
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
            String name = token.nextToken();
            String position = token.nextToken();
            String team = token.nextToken();
            int gp = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            int g = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            int pim = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            int sog = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            int gwg = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            pr = new PlayerRecord(name, position, team, gp, g, a, pim, sog, gwg);
            list.add(pr);
            }
        }
        input.close();
        list.enumerate();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```